# MBP & iMac - FacetimeHD green light but black screen

Tags: imac, video, facetime

My question: My Macbook Pro (2017) and iMac (2012) both seem to have a problem with the FacetimeHD camera: the green light turns on, but I get a black screen in all video apps like Zoom, Facetime and Photobooth. Both have worked perfectly before. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

They both run the latest version of Catalina. I've tried logging in safe mode, trying with a new user account, sudo killall commands, NVram and SMC resets, etc. basically everything above and on this list but no luck yet: https://appletoolbox.com/macbook-camera-not-working-or-not-available-here-are-12-ways-to-fix-it/

When I switched system languages, something happened, the video input turned out to work a little bit, but showing the captured video in grey / inverted colours. But after a reboot, the black screen reappeared.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Would be very grateful!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Instead of saying 'latest version' of Catalina, please [edit] your question to add your exact version number.  Also, you state this happened when you switched languages.  What steps did you take and did you do this to both MBP and iMac?